# Deselect ListBoxItem with delay

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties, triggers

I want to achieve an effect, where the `ListBoxItem` gets selected (highlighted) for a few seconds and after that it gets deselected. Trying to achieve a simple control highlight with fade effects but in order to make things work, I need a property to be changed accordingly.

I have a `IsSelected` property bound to my view model property:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Style>
```

My property looks like so:

```
public bool IsSelected
{
    get => _isSelected;
    set
    {
        // Update value
        _isSelected = value;

        // Raise property changed
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));
    }
}
```

I have tried using a delayed binding:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <!--  Deselect after 5 seconds  -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, Delay=5000}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I have also tried using storyboards:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <!--  Deselect after 5 seconds  -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsSelected">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:05" Value="False" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Unfortunately, none of the above approach seem to update my `IsSelected` property and the `ListBoxItem` remains selected and highlighted.

I want this to be done in XAML (or extensions), MVVM style, no code behind and no wasteful timers - is this possible? **If so, how can I properly deselect a `ListBoxItem` with a delay?**

Comment: Why would you want to implement something like this in XAML? It should be part of the control logic and XAML is a markup language. And what makes you think a timer is more wasteful than a `Storyboard`. It seems you have painted yourself into a corner with these requirements. MVVM is certainly not about eliminating view related code and implementing behavior in XAML.

Comment: @mm8 Making it part of the control logic would require to create one timer for each control. One solution would be to put a single timer into the list view model however I'm pretty certain this is not the best solution out there. I think this can be done using the attached properties (markup extensions), which would be 100% valid solution, but I'm out of ideas for now.

Comment: Attached behaviours are not "done in XAML" though so you may want to rephrase your question a bit.

Comment: @mm8 Right. did mention that in my question right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of an attached behaviour that should do what you want, more or less:

```
public class DeselectBehavior
{
    public static bool GetIsEnabled(ListBox listBox)
    {
        return (bool)listBox.GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsEnabled(ListBox listBox, bool value)
    {
        listBox.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsEnabled",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(DeselectBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnChanged));

    private static void OnChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox listBox = d as ListBox;
        if((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            listBox.AddHandler(ListBoxItem.SelectedEvent, (RoutedEventHandler)OnListBoxItemSelected, true);
        }
        else
        {
            listBox.RemoveHandler(ListBoxItem.SelectedEvent, (RoutedEventHandler)OnListBoxItemSelected);
        }
    }

    private static async void OnListBoxItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        ListBoxItem listBoxItem = e.OriginalSource as ListBoxItem;
        if (listBoxItem != null)
            listBoxItem.IsSelected = false;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
    <ListBox ... local:DeselectBehavior.IsEnabled="True">
    ...
```

Comment: `local:DeselectBehavior.IsEnabled="True"` how i can notify the use of this that this can be only used for `ListBox` . like lets say i have some another `attached behavior` which can only be use on a button.then when some on is used this on anything else while design how can notify them. or make a compile failed it possible?